# Right Alignment of Tab (When language is Arabic)

Tags: android, tabwidget

I am developing Android app with tab hosted.

I am using `TabWidget` with `TabHost`.

I want it right aligned with the language which is Arabic.

Please advise me the way to make `tabwidget` right aligned.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

Anyway, If you want to make every activity direction to RTL,  I'm recommending you to use "super activity" and use this in the class:

```
if (getWindow().getDecorView().getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I used the code in onResume function of activity. But it was not working. Can you please help me? Thanks

Comment: Attach it to onCreate.

Comment: Hi Eliran, Is it possible to exclude action bar from rtl alignment?

Comment: Did you try to add android:layoutDirection="ltr" there?